# Routing error after trying to make a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a confusing routing error after trying to submit a post. the error is `No route matches [POST] "/blog"` despite it being in routes.rb.

Here is my route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  get '/blog', to: 'posts#post', as: :post 
  get '/geobot', to: 'welcome#geobot', as: :geobot 
  get "/blog/show/:id", to: 'posts#show'
  get '/blog/new', to: 'posts#new', as: :new

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

and post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def post
    end 

    def new 
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        @post.save 
        redirect_to @post 
    end

    def show 
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end


    private 
     def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in your route.rb

```
...
post '/blog', to: 'posts#post', as: :post
...
```

first word is the method

Answer (score 0):

What have you defined? ( GET request )

> get '/blog', to: 'posts#post', as: :post

But it is expecting route '/blog' of type POST. So just define it

> post '/blog', to: 'posts#create', as: :post